# Я создаю программу которая будет с сайта загружать картинки но при запуске програми выдает таку ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я создаю программу которая будет с сайта загружать картинки но при запуске програми выдает таку ошибку[image: Это ошибка]

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import *

url = 'https://wallhaven.cc/search?q=id:55&ref=fp' 

def get_html():
    req = request(url)
    html = urlopen(req).read()
    return html

def main():
    opener = build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    install_opener(opener)
    for i in range(1,2):
        html = get_html(url+str(i))
        soup = BeautifulSaup(html , 'html.parser')
        list = soup.find_all(class_='preview')
        for a in list:
            secondary_html = get_html(a['href'])
            secondary_soup = BeautifulSaup(secondary_html , 'html.parser')
            image = secondary_soup.find(id='wallpaper')
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В следующей строке:

```py
html = get_html(url+str(i))
```

Вы передаёте функции `get_html` 1 позиционный аргумент (результат выражения `url+str(i)`).
Но в объявлении (`def get_html():`) не указано, что у функции есть параметры.
Вам необходимо явно указать, что функция принимает аргумент `url`.

Замените объявление на:

```py
def get_html(url):
```

---

В Вашем коде есть ещё несколько ошибок.

***Вот рабочий пример:***

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen, build_opener, install_opener


URL = 'https://wallhaven.cc/search?q=id:55&ref=fp'


def get_html(url):
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    return html


def main():
    opener = build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    install_opener(opener)

    for i in range(1, 2):
        html = get_html(URL + str(i))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

        li = soup.find_all(class_='preview')
        for a in li:
            secondary_html = get_html(a['href'])
            secondary_soup = BeautifulSoup(secondary_html, 'html.parser')
            image = secondary_soup.find(id='wallpaper')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @SimonC У Вас там ещё несколько ошибок. Попробуйте код, который я привёл.

Comment: @SimonC Что Вы имеете в виду? У Вас всё получилось?

Comment: @SimonC Это уже другой код, как я понимаю? У Вас ошибка отступов. Будет лучше, если Вы зададите новый вопрос и приложите к нему неработающий код с ошибкой.